# std::cin.putback() and "wake up" it

Tags: c++, multithreading, io

I have threads in my program and I want to put character into stream and read it in another thread, but after std::cin.putback() I need to write something from keyboard to "wake up" std::cin in function main. Can I do something to read automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not how streams work. The `std::cin` reads data that come from outside your program to standard input and the `putback` only allows keeping a character *that you actually just read* back to the buffer for re-parsing next time you invoke `operator>>` (or `get` or `getline` or other read method).

If you want to communicate between threads, you should use a message queue from some threading library, e.g. [Boost](http://www.boost.org) provides a decent portable one.

It is not possible to use streams, at least those provided by standard library, because `stringstream` is not thread-safe and `fistream`/`fostream` can't be created from raw file handle, so you can't combine them with POSIX `pipe` function. It would be possible to wrap a message queue in a stream (and boost gives you enough tools to do it), but the raw message queue API will probably be suitable.